# Passing array to useEffect dependency list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There's some data coming from long polling every 5 seconds and I would like my component to dispatch an action every time one item of an array (or the array length itself) changes.
How do I prevent useEffect from getting into infinity loop when passing an array as dependency to useEffect but still manage to dispatch some action if any value changes?

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(outcomes)
}, [outcomes])
```

where `outcomes` is an array of IDs, like `[123, 234, 3212]`. The items in array might be replaced or deleted, so the total length of the array might - but don't have to - stay the same, so passing `outcomes.length` as dependency is not the case.

`outcomes` comes from reselect's custom selector:

```
const getOutcomes = createSelector(
  someData,
  data => data.map(({ outcomeId }) => outcomeId)
)
```

Comment: Not enough context, please include the code that is actually causing the infinite loop

Comment: Spreading the array is no good. App starts with an empty array as default, so useEffect will throw error about different number of dependencies between rerenders.

Comment: Disappointing that none of these answers work with without warnings from react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can pass `JSON.stringify(outcomes)` as the dependency list:

Read more [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14476#issuecomment-471199055)

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(outcomes)
}, [JSON.stringify(outcomes)])
```

Comment: I'm quite sure this is the answer the OP wants. The idea also **isn't made up** by me. It's from [Dan Abramov (React core team member)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14476#issuecomment-471199055). If anyone sees there's a problem in my answer, please tell me what it is so that I can improve that answer to be better.

Comment: @user0101 Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I think I will actually give it a go. What's holding me back is 'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps' warning about ```oucomes``` being missing from deps. I know it makes no sense to add it since we added ```JSON.stringify(outcomes)``` but still

Comment: @user0101 to appease the linting, pass `outcomes` to the dependency list isn't a bad idea. *Execute this when `outcomes` change (being assigned to another array), or one of the items was changed*. The difference is when the array is being assigned to another array with the exact same identity, the effect is still executed.

Comment: I'm curious what you ended up with?

Comment: Hey, I ended up with `JSON.stringify(outcomes)` as dependency array

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh: I know why the answer works and I think it's a good answer, but with all the respect that I have for the React team because React is an amazing framework to build web apps with... this thing of passing arrays or objects to useEffect/useMemo/useCallback's dependencies really keeps coming back to me and I'm starting to get tired of using work-arounds. Is there any way we can discuss improvements somewhere? I don't know where to start.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I guess [opening a new issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues) in their repository might help.

Comment: this works perfect, but got complain from eslint

Comment: This causes ESLint to warn both about a missing dependency and a complex expression - both under the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps rule, which I really don't want to ignore. Maybe a custom deeply comparing hook would solve this? I don't know if ESLint would recognize a custom hook.

Comment: shouldnt we use .sort() and then stringify? what if the items change but length stayed the same?

Comment: @trainoasis it's `JSON.stringify(array)`, not `array.length`

Comment: My question still stands I think: the stringified could have same items but in a different order and that would still fire the useEffect, correct?

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` can be configured with additional hooks to be checked.

Comment: Am I the only getting the ESLint warning `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: outcomes` when using this method? The workaround is `const str = JSON.stringify(outcomes); useEffect(() => { const outcomes = JSON.parse(str); console.log(outcomes)}, [str])` but it's kinda verbose.

Comment: This should not be the answer. As noted in other comments, it does not fix the eslint warning. The React team repeatedly has said if you need to disable the warnings, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @ParkerD so what IS the right answer?

Answer (score 19):

Using `JSON.stringify()` or any deep comparison methods may be inefficient, if you know ahead the shape of the object, you can write your own effect hook that triggers the callback based on the result of your custom equality function.

`useEffect` works by checking if each value in the dependency array is the same instance with the one in the previous render and executes the callback if one of them is not. So we just need to keep the instance of the data we're interested in using `useRef` and only assign a new one if the custom equality check return `false` to trigger the effect.

```js
function arrayEqual(a1: any[], a2: any[]) {
  if (a1.length !== a2.length) return false;
  for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    if (a1[i] !== a2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

type MaybeCleanUpFn = void | (() => void);

function useNumberArrayEffect(cb: () => MaybeCleanUpFn, deps: number[]) {
  const ref = useRef<number[]>(deps);

  if (!arrayEqual(deps, ref.current)) {
    ref.current = deps;
  }

  useEffect(cb, [ref.current]);
}
```

#### Usage

```js
function Child({ arr }: { arr: number[] }) {
  useNumberArrayEffect(() => {
    console.log("run effect", JSON.stringify(arr));
  }, arr);

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(arr)}</pre>;
}
```

Taking one step further, we can also reuse the hook by creating an effect hook that accepts a custom equality function.

```js
type MaybeCleanUpFn = void | (() => void);
type EqualityFn = (a: DependencyList, b: DependencyList) => boolean;

function useCustomEffect(
  cb: () => MaybeCleanUpFn,
  deps: DependencyList,
  equal?: EqualityFn
) {
  const ref = useRef<DependencyList>(deps);

  if (!equal || !equal(deps, ref.current)) {
    ref.current = deps;
  }

  useEffect(cb, [ref.current]);
}
```

#### Usage

```js
useCustomEffect(
  () => {
    console.log("run custom effect", JSON.stringify(arr));
  },
  [arr],
  (a, b) => arrayEqual(a[0], b[0])
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 59467758/passing-array-to-useeffect-dependency-list]

Comment: This is the correct way to solve the problem (using `useRef`).

Comment: This answer is wrong, `useRef().current` can *not* be used in a dependency array: https://medium.com/welldone-software/usecallback-might-be-what-you-meant-by-useref-useeffect-773bc0278ae

Comment: @flyingsheep It's your argument that is wrong. Did you read the code and try running the demo? `ref.current` is a middle man variable that is used to store the new value which invokes the effect callback depend on the equality check. The one that triggers a re-render is the dependency value from the outside, not `ref.current`.

Comment: The answer contains `useEffect(cb, [ref.current])`, which is equivalent to `useEffect(cb)`.

Comment: @flyingsheep they're different as seen in this [demo](https://imgur.com/WX2Byqz), you can see the modified codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/59467758-passing-array-to-useeffect-dependency-list-forked-40o206?file=/src/App.tsx). the effect with the `ref.current` dependency only runs when the the `arr` prop changes, the ref is never meant to be reactive as intended.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive code and explanation @NearHuscarl, but I can't help being disgusted and refuse to write so much code for something that should be shipped out of the box. AFAIC I will JSON.stringify it and silence the warning.

Comment: I like this approach, and I adopted it. However, React complains that cb needs to be added as a dep to the useEffect call in useCustomEffect, but doing that wrecks my code. The array whose mutation I'm tracking as an effect is a list of options for a select. When I add cb as a dep, the select immediately closes every time I select it, so I see the options only for an instant. I added an eslint exception so I can use this solution, but the whole point of your answer was to provide a solution compatible with React dev guidance, so I'd like to know why this solution breaks the code as-is.

Answer (score 13):

Another ES6 option would be to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make it a string. Similar to `JSON.stringify()`, except the result won't be wrapped in `[]`

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(outcomes)
}, [`${outcomes}`])
```

Another option, **if the array size doesn't change**, would be to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it in:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(outcomes)
}, [ ...outcomes ])
```

Comment: Be aware that if you mix string with number in the array, the check may fail because `\`${[1,2,3]}\`` is the same as `\`${[1,2,'3']}\``. But storing values with different types in the same array is a bad idea anyway..

Comment: Unfortunately spreading returns a warning to me:
`React Hook useEffect has a spread element in its dependency array. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies`

Comment: The first one is the same as writing `outcomes.join()`

Answer (score 4):

As an addendum to [loi-nguyen-huynh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468261/1087131), for anyone encountering the **eslint exhaustive-deps warning**, this can be resolved by first breaking the stringified JSON out into a variable:

```
const depsString = JSON.stringify(deps);
React.useEffect(() => {
    ...
}, [depsString]);
```

Comment: You can't use `deps` inside the hook without getting a different `exhaustive-deps` warning, however. You also get a warning for *not* using the `depsString` in the hook. Is your answer to have to `JSON.parse` it within the effect? That seems ridiculous, honestly.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into this OSS package which was created to address the exact issue you describe (deeply comparing the values in the dependency array instead of shallow):

https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect

The usage/API is exactly the same as `useEffect` but it will compare deeply.

I would caution you however to not use it where you don't need it because it has the potential to result in a performance degredation due to unnecessary deep comparisons where a shallow one would do.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am suggesting here will match some scenarios. What I am doing for these kinds of issues is to memoize the variable and then useEffect will not fire indefinitely.

Please note this is not 100% match to the question asked above but I guess this will help someone.

```
const roles = useMemo(() => [EntityRole.Client, EntityRole.Agency], []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(roles)
}, [roles])
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I used the following approach to overcome such a situation: I simply passed an object containing the array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(outcomes)
}, [{outcomes}])
```

Comment: Creating a new object like this is just the same as not passing any deps: it will run each render.

Answer (score -1):

To fix linting issue, you can parse stingify variable within useEffect

```
  const getNames = (names) => {
      // stingify names list first
      const nameStr = JSON.stringify(names);

      useEffect(() => {
          // use stingify variable so useEffect don't have dependency on names
          const nameList = JSON.parse(nameStr);
          console.log(nameList);
      }, [nameStr]);
  };
```