# UseState returning data randomly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am fetching an API and setting some items :

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    function displayUser() {
      axios({
        // fetching logic ..
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        // result are return ..
        console.log("RESPONSE: ", res);
         // I wish to set items here 
        setItems(res.data[0]);
      });
    }


 useEffect(() => {
   displayUser() // executing my function

 }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("ITEMS AFTER: ", items);
    
    }, [items]);
```

The api return results each time, but it does not set the items everytime, it is very random and I don't know what is the problem.

If I console log the response from the API, I have my array, for the items it is random.

Comment: Can you paste the response example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setItems()` is the asynchronous method, and you can't get the updated value immediately after `setItems()`.

You should use another `useEffect` with adding a `items` dependency to check the updated state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("ITEMS: ",items)
}, [items]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I get the result, however how could I set my `displayUser()` function to work as well ? So far it is printing to the console with the second `useEffect` but If I run the function it just goes in infinite loop, thanks !

Comment: your code is correct, you can't get the updated value of items immediately after `setItems(res.data[0]);`.
you should use useEffect to check the state always.

Comment: So basically my function need to be re-design ?

Comment: no, you don't need to redesign, just check the items if it's empty to see if it's the initial value or the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Due to `items` is an array, you might see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467758/passing-array-to-useeffect-dependency-list). I suggest using `JSON.stringify(items)` as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("ITEMS: ",items)
}, [JSON.stringify(items)]);
```