# how to push multiple arrays to another array and update the value using useEffect properly in React JS?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

Hello I was trying to store some data in my array and I did try `allData.push(Data1, Data2, Data3)` but it said `.push` was not a function and it also didn't let me just `allData(Data1, Data2, Data3)`, w/e data I get it overrides the previous one. I also tried `allData(Data1+Data2+Data3)` finally I try something someone suggested me `setAllItems([LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3])` but it ended up looping and bringing an error:

[image]

My "closest" attempt so far has being this one :

```
useEffect(() => {
        let x = 0;
        
        LibrosID1.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio
        })
    
        LibrosID2.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio
        })
    
        LibrosID3.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio * i.necesita
        })
    
        setSubTotal(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        setAllItems([LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3])
    
        console.log(allItems)
      }, [LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3]);
```

What I do not understand is that I'm doing exactly the same with `setSubTotal` but that doesn't give me any kind of issue and it doesn't make sense that `setAllItems` give me an error and loop otherwise `setSubTotal` would loop and error as well right? so what am I doing wrong?

Any tips, documentation and help is welcome.

If you require the whole code let me know but I doubt is required.

**Update - Edit:**
So I fixed the loop bit and separated the code so people don't get confuse, but now I'm having a delay when I try to get data

```
useEffect(() => {
        setAllItems([LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3])
        console.log(allItems)
      }, [LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3]);
```

When I click the checkbox I get to see how the data is getting parse on LibrosID1 but it says 0 on allItems:

[image]

When I click the checkbox again it says 12, even though I just "uncheck" them.

[image]

I don't get it! *very frustrated atm*

Comment: It seems like it's stuck in an infinite loop based on your effect dependencies. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468261/9430279 This thread might be something you need.

Comment: Also, don't use `map()` unless you need the returned array, use `forEach` or a `for` loop. see: [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Comment: @pilchard the map is needed there because is grabbing an specific value from the array in this case the price for  `setSubTotal` and that bit is working perfectly fine. All I'm having issues is with sending the data from the arrays `LibrosID1` , `LibrosID2` , `LibrosID3`

Comment: After you solve useEffect loop problem, you can combine arrays with es6 spread operator : [...arr1,...arr2,...arr3]

Comment: @cansu I'm doing that `setAllItems([LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
let librosID1 = ["a"];
let librosID2 = ["b"];
let librosID3 = ["c"];

const [allItems, setAllItems] = useState(null);
const [subTotal, setSubTotal] = useState();

useEffect(() => {

  setAllItems([...librosID1, ...librosID2, ...librosID3]);
}, []);

console.log(allItems)
```

The spread operator is used to display or combine all elements from objects or arrays.

References:

Spread syntax (...). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax. (Accessed 28 September, 2021).

Comment: whats the difference between `setAllItems([LibrosID1, LibrosID2, LibrosID3])` vs `setAllItems([...librosID1, ...librosID2, ...librosID3]);` ?

Comment: @ReactPotato I added an explanation to my answer.  The link in the references has more details.