# React returning empty array after populating it (possibly re-render problem)

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I load a contact from a parent component which is sent to `EditMainContact`, which is a dialog/modal form where values are set inside inputs to edit them. So I use `contacto` as trigger of a useEffect so when it loads or changes, the relative data is converted into 2 arrays that I will use later. These are `tels_empresa` and `emails_empresa`.
At the same time, when these change, the values for the form are populated (this is where it doesn't work). It shows one input with the very last value. I am probably missing something here, maybe this is rerendering for some reason and at the end it returns a *empty-ish* array. The code is way longer than this but I put here the data I find necessary for the issue.

```
export default function EditMainContact({contacto}) {
    const [tels_empresa,setTels_empresa] =useState();
    const [emails_empresa,setEmails_empresa] =useState();
    const [telFormValues, setTelFormValues] = useState([]); 
    const [emailFormValues, setEmailFormValues] = useState([]);  
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        setTels_empresa(contacto?.telefonos_empresa?.split(",").map(par=>par.split(":")));
        setEmails_empresa(contacto?.emails_empresa?.split(",").map(par=>par.split(":")));
    },[contacto]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        tels_empresa?.map((inp, index)=>{
            setTelFormValues([...telFormValues,{tel_identificador: inp[0], tel: inp[1]}]);
            setFormValues({...formValues, ["telefonos_empresa"]: telFormValues});
        });
    },[tels_empresa]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        emails_empresa?.map((inp, index)=>{ 
            setEmailFormValues([...emailFormValues,{email_identificador: inp[0],email:inp[1]}]);
            setFormValues({...formValues, ["emails_empresa"]: emailFormValues});
        });
    },[emails_empresa])

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing array to useEffect dependency list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467758/passing-array-to-useeffect-dependency-list)

Comment: I may be wrong but to my knowledge, this is not related to my issue.

Comment: Did you try to use the suggested solution of wrapping the useEffect dependencies like this - `[JSON.stringify(tels_empresa)]` and `[JSON.stringify(emails_empresa)]`?

Comment: Yes, same result with or without stringify.

Comment: So my next suggestion is to use previous value in the setter, like this: `setTelFormValues((prevTelFormValues) => [...prevTelFormValues, {tel_identificador: inp[0]...` cause in the useEffect scope you may not have the up to date value of `telFormValues`. (apply same thing to the other setters)

Comment: Worth mentioning that The objects I'm mapping `tels_empresa` and `emails_empresa` are populated correctly and contain all the data. Something is failing when using ```setEmailFormValues([...emailFormValues,{email_identificador: inp[0], email : inp[1]}]);```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244684/discussion-between-hedeh-and-german).

Comment: Your suggestion of `prevTelFormValues` worked! I dont understand why since In my code I was using ...telFormValues which represents the current array data. I don't see why this makes a difference, but it does! Please Add it is answer so I can check it as solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that inside the `useEffect` callback's scope you don't have the up to date values of `telFormValues`, `emailFormValues` and `formValues`.

Every time `tels_empresa` or `emails_empresa` changes, the `useEffect` callback gets recreated and runs, but it points to an "old" value of the other consts you use inside the callback's scope.

To fix this you have 2 options:

1. Add the other consts to the dependencies array. (but this will make the useEffect run also when the other consts change)
2. Use the setter previous value functionality. This makes sure you are getting the up to date value. Here is an example: (and you need to do the same for the other setters)

   `setTelFormValues((prevTelFormValues) => [...prevTelFormValues, {tel_identificador: inp[0]...`