# Component re-render every time custom hook value returned gets updated in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm encountering an issue with a custom hook called `useAnswerProgress`. Whenever the component that calls this hook re-renders, the hook returns an empty array, even though the content of the array hasn't actually changed.

Here's a code pen that demonstrates the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nz6eru?file=src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev

This is a simplified version of the code with just the steps required to reproduce the issue.

The `useAnswerProgress` hook is used inside a component and returns a list that gets updated every time there is a new record or a delete record. This list is then set to an `useState` inside a temporary variable. However, on re-render, this causes an error

[image]

I'm not sure why does this re-render every time. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like an issue related to passing array as useEffect dependency, check out this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467758/passing-array-to-useeffect-dependency-list